# Dependencies from Docker image not found in the running container

Tags: linux, docker, ubuntu, webpack, dockerfile

#### Background

So I'm trying to set up a Docker container for development, and one of my dependencies is `webpack`.

#### Repo Steps:

1. install this in the image with an npm install webpack.
2. The image builds successfully
3. I run it
4. In the Docker Desktop GUI shell I type `webpack -v`
5. Then get output `webpack: command not found.`

#### Question

How does it not find the command if it was one of the dependencies installed on the base image?

Comment: `How does it not find the command if it was one of the dependencies installed on the base image?` Then, if the following is true, it does not find a command, a simple deduction should be enough to come to the conclusion, that the installation was invalid or unsuccessful... What more an answer do you expect? Please create an [MCVE]. Please post your `Dockerfile`, please post all the steps. Please _show_ `run it` - what exactly do you run? What image are you using? How did you build it?